# How to do a statistical analysis?

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis

I am sorry for my profound knowledge of statistics and for this candid question. Your help is valued.

I have the following data.

Data1 (stress-I)::   24    35    53    15    40    37    58    11    34    27    34    10    22    40 45    10    42    31    11    16    31    20    34    29    31    26    54    37

Data2 (stress-II)::   23    35    28    14    38    39    40    24    28    32    14    28    33    38  30    25    30    18    20    26    16    30    32    26    38    32    38    38

My task is to find a relation between these data by using some kind of statistical analysis.

I am not sure of which statistical analysis tool/technique to use and how to interpret the result.

Answer (score 7):

There are plenty of things you might do initially.  For example using R you might start data exploration with something like

```
stressdata <- data.frame(Data1 = c(24, 35, 53, 15, 40, 37, 58, 11, 34, 27, 
                                   34, 10, 22, 40, 45, 10, 42, 31, 11, 16, 
                                   31, 20, 34, 29, 31, 26, 54, 37), 
                         Data2 = c(23, 35, 28, 14, 38, 39, 40, 24, 28, 32, 
                                   14, 28, 33, 38, 30, 25, 30, 18, 20, 26, 
                                   16, 30, 32, 26, 38, 32, 38, 38) )
summary(stressdata) 

cor(stressdata$Data1, stressdata$Data2)

plot(stressdata, xlim=c(0,50), ylim=c(0,50))
```

and get something like

```
> summary(stressdata) 
     Data1           Data2      
 Min.   :10.00   Min.   :14.00  
 1st Qu.:21.50   1st Qu.:24.75  
 Median :31.00   Median :30.00  
 Mean   :30.61   Mean   :29.04  
 3rd Qu.:37.75   3rd Qu.:35.75  
 Max.   :58.00   Max.   :40.00  
> 
> cor(stressdata$Data1, stressdata$Data2)
[1] 0.5059039
```

and

[image]

So you can see that the two sets of data seem to be paired.  You might then want to investigate whether it is plausible that they come from the same distribution, for example by looking the means and variances.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest a tool, in fear of encouraging bad statistics...but if you have spreadsheet software (Excel? [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)?), you might try a plotting an X-Y graph, since you have only that much data. That often exposes any relationship. You should be able to plot a regression line, and there are functions for getting intercept, slope, correlation, etc.

But mostly you should learn statistics. :)